# Want to see the image only in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a button connected to an action.
When I set the background image on that button, the result is not visually appealing.  I want just to see the image not the button but I want the ibaction functionality of that button.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a button with type UIButtonTypeCustom (this will stop the default button appearance from drawing). You can do this in interface builder or in code (although you can't change it once the button is initialized).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did change the button to UIButtonTypeCustom in IB.  I can't figure out what else has to be changed so I just see the image and not the button itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "the button itself". The rounded rect with button text in it?

Comment: I don't have any text and I don't want to see the rounded rectangle either.  I just want to see the image but I want to be able to click on the image and be directed to an IBaction.

Comment: If you've properly set the button type to custom in interface builder, you should not see the rounded rect.